# Unable to calculate total amount in integer, between activities in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I am making an application in which i have to fetch item name and price from first activity to another and i am able to do that but in second activity i am allowing user to put quantity in numbers and whenever user will click on button a `TextView` to show total amount, but not able to calculate total Amount for item.

I know this is very simple task to do but i am getting error while write this line in button `onClick()`:

```
txtResult=txtCost*txtQty
```

here i am placing second activity code,

please correct this one:-

```
public class SecondScreenActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen2);

    TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    TextView txtCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCost);
    EditText txtQty=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtQty);
    Button btnClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);
    TextView txtResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResult);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    // Receiving the Data
    String name = i.getStringExtra("name");
    String cost = i.getStringExtra("cost");

    // Displaying Received data
    txtName.setText(name);
    txtCost.setText(cost);

    // Binding Click event to Button
    btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //Closing SecondScreen Activity
            //finish();
            txtResult=txtCost*txtQty;

        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Those are not int values.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by

```
int cost = Integer.parseInt(txtCost.getText().toString());
int qty =  Integer.parseInt(txtQty.getText().toString());
int result = cost*qty;
```

and then set this result into txtResult

```
txtResult.setText(result+"");
```

or you can convert int to String and then apply setText

Answer (score 0):

```
   txtResult=txtCost*txtQty;
```

These are TextView objects. You can't do maths on objects. Get the textview's values into integers and then try to multiply.

Do something like this.. depending on the type of variable you want (integer, float, double).

```
int a = new Integer(txtCost.getText().toString());
int b = new Integer(txtQty.getText().toString());
int c = a * b;
txtResult.setText(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are to multiplying value in Textview

```
 btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View arg0) {
Float f_name = new Float(name);
Float f_cost = new Float(cost);
Float f_result=f_name *f_cost ;
txtResult.setText(f_result);

   }
    });

}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There are 2 changes that needs to be made.

1. Make both txtCost and txtQty global variables.
2. both these variables cannot be directly multiplied. Instead do somthing like this.

   ```
   double cost = Double.parseDouble(txtCost.getText().toString());
   double qty = Double.parseDouble(txtQty.getText().toString());

   txtResult = cost * qty ;
   ```

Comment: txtResult is also a TextView , make required changes